# $_product doesn't contain all needed data (minimal_price)

Tags: product, configurable-product

Basically, my problem is that I need to get the minimal_price of an configurable product in category view. Previously, this worked by using

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();

$_product->getMinimalPrice();
```

However, it doesn't work anymore. I noticed, that when it still worked dumping $_product would contain 'minimal_price'. Now, this is not the case anymore. Does anyone know what the reason could be?

Comment: Did you enable flat products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input from everyone.
Melvyn was right, flat products weren't enabled. I think I had it once enabled but the index wasn't refreshed. Thinking about it that was really obvious but until I found out the page became so slow because minimal_price was missing took forever. 
So thanks a lot, Melvyn!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
$tier_price = end($_product->getTierPrice());
echo $tier_price['price'];
```